# How "Candidate score" is calculated?

Tags: discussion, election

*I "am" interested in nominating for the mod election, but I feel that I don't have all the necessary experience yet. (My plan is to become more experienced over the months so I can nominate in the next election cycle, whenever that may be.)*

With that out of the way, how would I know what my "candidate score" would be if I did nominate?

I am particularly curious as to what badges are selected to count towards:

- the "moderation badges: 8/8",
- the "editing badges: 6/6", and
- the "participation badges: 6/6"

Comment: Awesome to hear this, I've definitely noticed your activity recently and the effort is much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a post with the details on [the SE Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252641/what-are-the-details-on-the-candidate-score-which-shows-during-an-election). As far as the badges go, they are:

> - 1 point each for Moderation badges - [Civic Duty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty), [Cleanup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/4/cleanup), [Deputy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/140/deputy), [Electorate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/electorate), [Marshal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/160/marshal), [Reviewer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/169/reviewer), [Sportsmanship](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/119/sportsmanship), [Steward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/185/steward) - for a maximum of 8 points.
> - 1 point each for Editing badges - [Copy Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/65/copy-editor), [Explainer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/246/explainer), [Organizer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/5/organizer), [Refiner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/247/refiner), [Strunk and White](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white), [Tag Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/73/tag-editor) - for a maximum of 6 points.
> - 1 point each for Participation badges - [Constituent](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent), [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention), [Enthusiast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/39/enthusiast), [Investor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/61/investor), [Quorum](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/900/quorum), [Yearling](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling) - for a maximum of 6 points.

There is a [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/android/query/298418/candidate-score) that will calculate your current score without having to actually submit a nomination.

Comment: [Matthew also posted a link on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28250585#28250585) to [check what badges you are missing](http://data.stackexchange.com/android/query/390710/badges-missing-from-election-candidate-score)

Comment: Thanks for the useful info. I just found all the required badges hidden inside tooltips on the election page, you have to hover over each category for a couple seconds to see them. Very discreet!